# Unable to invoke @HostListener method in the Unit Test case

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-directive

I have created a custom Directive using `@Directive` in which I am using `@HostListener` and the code works fine.
Now, when writing the test case I need to invoke the `@HostListener` method from the unit test case. Also I can see that in the code coverage the code is not covered.
Following is the code:

**focus-encapsulation.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appFocusEncapsulation]'
})
export class FocusEncapsulationDirective {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
  keyDown(event: Event) {
    console.log('event : ', event);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

}
```

**focus-encapsulation.directive.spec.ts**

```
import { FocusEncapsulationDirective } from './focus-encapsulation.directive';
import { Component, ElementRef, DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from "@angular/platform-browser";

@Component({
  template: `<div appFocusEncapsulation><button type="button" (click)="add()">ADD</button></div>`
})
class TestHoverFocusComponent {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { 
    console.log('in constructor')
  }
}

fdescribe('FocusEncapsulationDirective', () => {

  let component: TestHoverFocusComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestHoverFocusComponent>;
  let inputEl: DebugElement;
  let elementRef: ElementRef

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [TestHoverFocusComponent, FocusEncapsulationDirective]
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestHoverFocusComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    elementRef = fixture.nativeElement;
    inputEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button'));
  });

  it('should create an instance', () => {
    const directive = new FocusEncapsulationDirective(elementRef)
    expect(directive).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('Focus over elements', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const event = {
      which : 9,
      keyCode : 9,
      srcElement :{
        innerText : 'ADD'
      },
      preventDefault: function() {
        console.log('preventDefault() method called');
      }
    }
    spyOn(event, 'preventDefault');
    inputEl.triggerEventHandler('keydown', event);
    expect(event.preventDefault()).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

});
```

Below you can also see the code coverage report:
[image]

Here I need to cover the code and get the proper test case executed required for this method. Thanks.

Comment: You haven't added the directive to the declarations of your testing module.

Comment: I did not get you... Where should I add this.. is there any file or something..

Comment: `TestBed.configureTestingModule({
   declarations: [TestHoverFocusComponent, FocusEncapsulationDirective]
});`.

Comment: oops! now, updated the code. BTW it still doesn't work :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a fixed version of your test:

```
fdescribe('FocusEncapsulationDirective', () => {

  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestHoverFocusComponent>;
  let inputEl: HTMLElement;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [TestHoverFocusComponent, FocusEncapsulationDirective]
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestHoverFocusComponent);
    inputEl = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('button');
  });

  it('Focus over elements', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const event = new Event('keydown', { bubbles: true });
    spyOn(event, 'preventDefault');
    inputEl.dispatchEvent(event);
    expect(event.preventDefault).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

});
```

Key points:

- you need to pass the spied function itself, to expect(), to check that it has been called. Your code *calls* the spied function, and passes what it returns to epect().
- You need to pass an actual event (and especially one that has its `bubbles` flag set to true, otherwise the event won't bubble, and the listener on the enclosing `div` will thus not be notified of the event triggered on the enclosed button) to the native DOM element .